# GameDev : Engine/Graphics API/Custom?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, game-engine, game-physics

I'd like to create a game that has a platform, with various floors. Each floor has some buildings and objects on it that can be interacted with and has some way of getting to floors above it and/or below it.

I need to have: Object(Model) Loading/Rendering, Input, Collision Detection and Picking.
I'd also like to stick to .NET Langauges

I have looked up many engines (both .NET native or with a wrapper) and many have these features that I need and more often than not, extra features I don't want nor need.

I have looked at Grahpics APIs sich as DirectX/OpenGL and other Grahpics APIs based upon these, however I would need to write Collision Detection and picking functions myself, or bind to something such as Newton Physics or PhysX.

*EDIT: I have also looked at XNA but I have seen/read mixed reviews about it's design.*

I have also considered writing my own functions or the use of 3rd Party Libraires to Load/Render and further Collision detection and picking written by myself.

From a purely theoretical point of view I am wanting to complete this project as a educational project, but not so indepth or labourious I end up pulling my hair out and going through many a computer screen.

My programming knowledge is self taught from VB -> C# and some C. I can do basic Object Orientated work (Properties, Inheritance, Polymorphism) but have no clue about Constructors and Accsessors and Destructures and other features I've probably not mentioned. I have around A-level(English System/Advanced Higher(Scotish System) Maths knowledge and GCSE (English)/ Higher (Scotish) Physics knowledge that I'd need for the Vectors and Collision detection.

So my question is - what would be the **quickest, most educational** way **while still being fun and not labourious** to complete this project - Using Engine(s) and learning their functions / Graphics APIs with custom Collision Detection or writing everything from scratch and/or using 3rd Libraries to aid me? Or even am I going about this in the wrong frame of mind/approach, can I be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: There is a GameDev Stack Exchange site. And for long, open-ended questions like these it may make more sense to use an actual discussion forum, such as http://www.gamedev.net. This question cannot be reasonably answered on a Q/A site.

Comment: gamedev.net doesn't work for me. I have tired creating an account but I never get any emails to register and in doing so means I am effectively blocked from seeing anything. This could be a Firefoxism, but I have found the same problem with IE.

Comment: I would suggest improving your development skills first to learn about constructors & accessors etc as the majority of frameworks will probably blow your mind to start off with. Take a look at the source SDK for example: http://hg.alliedmods.net/hl2sdks/hl2sdk-css/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). You can build a game using a decent designer, it has a lot of tools (physics engine, particle systems, rendering, etc...).

You can script behaviour in Javascript, C# or Boo which ever you prefer the most.

And you can release your game to android, IOS, PS3, XBOX, WII, PC, MAC, Web Playerand Flash and the basic version is free.

If you want to stick to pure .NET check out XNA

Edit: to add to your lack of OOP skills I think that you would find unity easier since you focus less on the software engineering stuff and focus on scripting the behaviour of the objects. It is fun, and you'll learn a lot. Maybe you will not learn how the scene is being rendered underneath but you'll get more programming experience and once you have that you can start exploring lower level stuff ...